# Sort the tables in the order of FK references?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to sort a list of tables in the order of FK dependency with the least depended tables on top?

For example, table `A` has a FK references `B`, which has FK references `C`. The result should be

```
    C
    B
    A
```

```
select * from sys.tables order by .....?
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
select a.Name
from sys.tables a
    LEFT JOIN sys.foreign_keys b ON a.object_id = b.parent_object_id
GROUP BY a.Name
ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT b.name) ASC
```

Comment: Count may not be good - for example, C will not be in frond of B if C is only referenced by B but A and  B are referenced by a lot of tables.

Comment: Did you try it? I'm using a LEFT join on sys.foreign_keys, which means C does not have to be referenced by anything, and COUNT(DISTINCT b.name) for C will return 0, whereas COUNT(DISTINCT b.name) for A and B will return 1. I ran it on my DB, and the results looked correct?

Answer (score 1):

In general case you can have multiple graphs of dependencies with loops. I would not try to do it in SQL. It is a rather difficult problem.

1) Extract all pairs of parent - child tables from sys.tables and make a simple long list of all dependencies.

2) Use something like "dot" from http://www.graphviz.org/ to process these pairs and generate a graph.

I personally use this approach to visualize graph of dependencies between salespeople that are stored in my database.

Out of curiosity I did it for all foreign keys in my database. Each node here is a table.

[image: keys]

You can't see all details on this screenshot, but it is enough to get the idea. I can now easily find tables that are at the top and bottom of the dependency chain (they are in the left-most and right-most columns on the graph).

I used this query:

```
select 
    '"'+ParentTables.name+'" -> "'+ReferencedTables.name+'";' AS dot
from
    sys.foreign_keys
    inner join sys.tables AS ParentTables ON ParentTables.object_id = sys.foreign_keys.parent_object_id
    inner join sys.tables AS ReferencedTables ON ReferencedTables.object_id = sys.foreign_keys.referenced_object_id
```

Put results in a text file keys.txt, first line of the text file is:

```
digraph G { rankdir=LR
```

last line of the text file is

```
}
```

Command line to generate the graph:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin\dot.exe" -okeys_graph_20150117.png -Tpng keys.txt
```